# Official interim procedure for doing retagging.

Tags: discussion, retagging, policy

**Background**. 
For purpose of discussion, let A and B be tags, and let the goal be to convert B to A. There are two independent methods for doing this:

1. (**Looking forward**): Creating a *tag synonym* A $\leftarrow $B ensures that *in the future*, any time that tag B is entered, it is silently converted to tag A.
2. (**Looking back**): *Merging* tag B into tag A ensures that after the moment of merging, no more B tags exist, all having been converted to tag A.

**Properties**

- Synonyms are not linked to 'interesting'/'uninteresting' filters, so a filter for B will not return questions labelled A after the above synonym is created
- Synonyms are **community-created**: anyone with 1000+ rep can propose a synonym and if it gets 4+ votes it is **automatically** approved. Conversely, -2 votes **automatically** kill it.
- Merging does not preclude new instances of B from appearing.
- **Merging is irrevocable**: synonyms are not.

**Discussion**
Ideally, synonyms do not require any moderator intervention. However, in our current state we don't have enough high rep users who participate at a meta level to create synonyms, and we haven't had any serious tag wars yet. However, we do want to clean up tags, just to make things a little more organized for searching/filtering.

while I can imagine situations where a merge of B to A need not be followed by creating the synonym A $\leftarrow$ B (B is a spam tag and we don't want to clutter the tag synonym list), I suspect that for a while, we will want to do both merging and synonyms together.

**Proposed policy: merge+synonym**

1. Someone creates a RETAG request
2. If a request gets at least T votes, then someone should flag the post for moderator attention and a moderator can create the synonym AND merge prior tags.

And T = 4.

We can revisit this later on if needed.

Comment: Sounds good, but what about the "remove cs. prefix" proposal + [related changes](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/118/proposal-remove-discipline-prefix-from-the-arxiv-style-tags/132#132); should we create a lot of retag requests for those?

Comment: I think we can go ahead with those. I've been doing them slowly just to make sure nothing breaks. No need to file retag requests

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Suresh’s post](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/retag-all-cs-xyz-abc-to-xyz-abc/345#345) to another discussion, some tag synonyms are created without their master tags being created.  However, I think that some reconsideration is desirable because creating a tag synonym whose master tag does not exist in the system seems to have caused two problems.

1. Some tag-related pages are Not Found.  See comments to [Suresh’s post](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/retag-all-cs-xyz-abc-to-xyz-abc/345#345).
2. Users with rep less than 200 cannot tag his/her own question with either the older tag or the newer tag until some user with rep ≥200 uses the newer tag, even if the older tag is in use.  See a note and comments in a [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/confidentiality-of-partial-private-keys-in-certificateless-public-key-crypto) by Zack (but let’s avoid discussing about the issue on the question page).

Judging from [how the feature of tag synonyms was requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) on meta.stackoverflow.com, it seems to me that a tag synonym is supposed to be created when the master tag is already in use.  Therefore, it is understandable that the system behaves oddly if the master of a tag synonym has not been created.

Comment: How about this then. We can do merges first followed by synonyms for now

Comment: @Suresh: Merging followed by creating synonyms sounds good if it is not too troublesome for you.

Comment: I did a whole round, including crypto and distributed comp. I'll wait for a few more to pile up before doing the next batch.

Comment: @Suresh: Thanks!