# RETAG: distributed-systems -> dc.distributed-comp

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Now it should be ok to merge [distributed-systems](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributed-systems) -> [dc.distributed-comp](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc.distributed-comp).

---

**Edit:** This has got so far only 1 supporting vote, and according to [our policy](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/official-interim-procedure-for-doing-retagging), the threshold is 4 votes before the moderators can act. Why the lack of support? To me this looks like a no-brainer; the tags are now synonymous (recall that we have now a separate tag for dc.parallel-comp), and currently the more popular tag is the "wrong" one (non-arxiv), so merging would help to clean up the situation.

If you have some specific doubts regarding this proposal, please leave a comment. If you think this is a bad idea, feel free to downvote.

---

**Edit:** It seems that we are getting more and more questions with the [distributed-systems] tag and *no* top-level arxiv tag. By now we have already 8 such questions. And as far as I can tell, all of those questions *could* be equally well tagged with [dc.distributed-comp]. Hence I am once again editing this in an attempt to attract the missing supporting vote – if this fails, I promise I will stop bothering you with this issue. :)

Comment: we do have a policy on how to retag: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/271/official-interim-procedure-for-doing-retagging

Comment: I think that the issue might be just that not many people involved in the subject have seen this request.  I do not know anything about distributed systems or distributed computation, and I will not vote for or against it to avoid the same mistake I made before (I asked for a wiki edit not knowing that there was separate tags for machine learning and learning theory).

Comment: Thanks! .......