# Rename and synonymize the tags [prg], [pseudorandomness] → [pseudorandom-generators]

Tags: support, retag-request

*Edit: I take back this proposal.  See [Suresh’s answer](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/803/rename-and-synonymize-the-tags-prg-pseudorandomness-pseudorandom-generato/805#805).*

---

I think that the tags [prg](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prg) and [pseudorandomness](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudorandomness) have no distinction and should be merged.  Also, they can be renamed to a new tag [pseudorandom-generators](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudorandom-generators) for clarity.  Therefore, I propose the following:

- Rename [prg](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prg) and [pseudorandomness](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudorandomness) to [pseudorandom-generators](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudorandom-generators).
- Make [prg](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prg) and [pseudorandomness](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudorandomness) synonyms for [pseudorandom-generators](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudorandom-generators).
- Cancel my older [proposal](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags/pseudorandomness/synonyms) to make [prg](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prg) a tag synonym for [pseudorandomness](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudorandomness), which I started without considering alternatives.

**Note**.  This is a [retag request](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/official-interim-procedure-for-doing-retagging), and it will be considered to be approved when it reaches the score of +4.

Comment: I think the tag [prg] (and [pseudorandom-generators]) is used for questions about generators and [pseudorandom] as more general, but don't know if what I said makes much sense. If we are going to keep only one, I would prefer to keep [pseudorandomness] more than [pseudorandom-generators] because it is (seems) more general.

Comment: @Kaveh: If you can see any distinction between the two tags in the actual usage on cstheory.stackexchange.com, please tell me.  I cannot find any distinction.

Comment: I agree with Kaveh: while there may not be a distinction in the question, pseudorandomness is the broader notion that can cover generators as well as tools for testing randomness, and complexity-related topics like the hardness vs randomness tradeoff, and so on.

Comment: @Suresh: Fine.  Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I think right now the sample is too small to show any meaningful distinction. Btw, we also have the related tags: [tag:derandomization], [tag:randomness], [tag:randomized-algorithms].

Comment: @Kaveh or anyone other than me: Please post it as an _answer_!!  I cannot accept an answer posted by myself without waiting for 2 days or so, and I do not want to do that anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there may not be a distinction in the question, pseudorandomness is the broader notion that can cover generators as well as tools for testing randomness, and complexity-related topics like the hardness vs randomness tradeoff, and so on. I support changing `prg` to `pseudorandomness-generator`, but not any of the other recommendations.

Comment: Thanks, I take my proposal back.  Needless to say, if anyone is willing to write a new proposal based on this, I am fine with that.