# Proposal: Rename the tag [dynamic] to [dynamic-algorithms]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I propose to rename the tag [dynamic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) (currently 8 questions) to [dynamic-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-algorithms) (currently nonexistent), because the questions with the tag are really about dynamic algorithms, that is, algorithms about certain objects with online updates.

(There was [one closed question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/variable-profit-knapsack) where the tag [dynamic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) was used to mean dynamic programming.  I modified this tag manually.)

I cannot use the existing system for creating a tag synonym (which would automatically merge the created tag synonym to the real tag) because the tag [dynamic-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-algorithms) does not exist at this moment.  Therefore, I would like to invoke the [official interim procedure for doing retagging](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/official-interim-procedure-for-doing-retagging) for this purpose.  This means:

> Score +4 or more of this meta post is interpreted as a consensus that the tag [dynamic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) should be renamed to [dynamic-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-algorithms).

I do **not** think that the old tag [dynamic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) should be a tag synonym after renaming, but I do not have a strong opinion about this.

Comment: dynamic-algorithms or dynamic-data-structures?

Comment: @Kaveh: That is a good point.  They refer to the same thing, but I do not know which is more widely recognized.

Comment: I'm ok with the tag saying dynamic algorithms but meaning both

Comment: we can also make dynamic-data-structures a synonym for the other one.

Comment: For the record, this post reached score +4, and I flagged for moderator attention with the following message: “(1) This post has score +4.  Please rename the tag [dynamic] to [dynamic-algorithms].  (2) I do not think that [dynamic] should be kept as a synonym, but I do not have a strong opinion about this.”

Comment: This update has now been made.

Comment: @Suresh: Thanks!